# подсветка на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript

У меня не получается сделать подсветку при нажатии клавиши на клавиатуре.
Подскажите пожалуйста что не так в JS коде. Спасибо.

JS

```
document.onkeypress = function (event) {
    console.log(event.code);
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    document.querySelector('#first-level .center[data = "' + event.keyCode + '"]').classList.add('downKeybord');
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="first-level">
    <div class="apostrophe center" data="192">`</div>
    <div class="one center" data="49">1</div>
    <div class="two center" data="50">2</div>
    <div class="three center" data="51">3</div>
    <div class="four center" data="52">4</div>
    <div class="five center" data="53">5</div>
    <div class="six center" data="54">6</div>
    <div class="seven center" data="55">7</div>
    <div class="eight center" data="56">8</div>
    <div class="nine center" data="57">9</div>
    <div class="zero center" data="48">0</div>
    <div class="dash center" data="189">-</div>
    <div class="equal center" data="187">=</div>
    <div class="backspace center" data="8">Backspace</div>
</div>
```

В CSS я сделала клавиши белого цвета, и класс downKeybord:

```
.downKeybord {
    background-color: #7c7a7d;
}
```

Comment: на вашем месте я бы начал того, чтобы атрибут назвать не `data` а `data-value`

Comment: и switch case в добавок

Answer (score 1):

уберите пробелы из селектора между data и =

```
 document.querySelector('#first-level .center[data="' + event.keyCode + '"]').classList.add('downKeybord');
```

тогда все работает

Comment: почему-то дальше не работает и выбивает такую ошибку: 
Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLDocument.document.onkeypress

Comment: @Марта, скрипт помещен ниже HTML кода? Или вызывается с задержкой? Ошибка говорит, что у Вас не правильный селектор или же нет такого элемента

Comment: @Node_pro, скрипт размещен в отдельном файле

Comment: Добавлю тоже самое, что и @Node_pro - при тестировании я поставил сначала html код, потом css (что не так важно), потом javascript - возможно для javascript вам необходимо поставить запуск после загрузки документа

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded - вот здесь описана ситуация: "Когда браузер обрабатывает HTML-документ и встречает тег <script>, он должен выполнить его перед тем, как продолжить строить DOM." - добавьте в скрипт window.onload , даже если он в отдельном файле